Firestore query with multiple filters
Using Dart/Flutter and the package cloud_firestore: ^4.17.5, I am building the method getQuestions that receives the following parameters below. I need to search for questions in the database using these filters that can be null, considering that they are lists coming from multiple selects and firestore does not accept multiple where in, what is the best solution for this problem, since the limit in a first search can harm the filtering if done locally and if the limit parameter is removed the search can be very costly because there are millions of questions records in the database?
String? creatorUserId;
String? type;
bool? isAnnulled;
String? statement;
List<String>? examCompanyIds;
List<String>? institutionIds;
List<String>? disciplineIds;
List<String>? topicIds;
List<String>? positionIds;
List<String>? educationFieldIds;
List<String>? regionIds;
List<String>? areaIds;
List<String>? scholarityIds;
List<String>? difficultyIds;
List<String>? yearIds;
DateTime? createdAtStart;
DateTime? createdAtEnd;
int limit;

I'm not a NoSQL expert, I would actually like to know from you what the best solution is. How would you implement this? Client-side or using Cloud Functions?
Note that I have six parameters that need to use where and the parameters that are lists, which are 11, should use whereIn. Which makes it difficult to implement on the client side due to Firestore limitations.
Note: The questions collection data is denormalized. So the implementation of the query for the parameters that are lists would look something like this:
Query query = _firestore.collection('questions');

// Adds common filters
if (params.creatorUserId != null) {
 query = query.where('creatorUserId', isEqualTo: params.creatorUserId);
}

// [...] more common filters

// Adds `whereIn` filters
if(params.examCompanyIds.isNotEmpty) {
  query = query.where('examCompany.uid', whereIn: params.examCompanyIds);
}

// [...] more `whereIn` filters

final result = query.limit(params.limit).get();



"it didn't work" is not very easy to help with. Is there an error message? If not, did you already step through the code line-by-line, inspecting the value of each variable on each line? If so, what was the first time that something wasn't as you expected it to be?

Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Please respond using @AlexMamo

I edited it and put a little explanation in the Edit Summary. @AlexMamo

So to understand better, the problem is related to the fact that you cannot call where in multiple times, right?

Exactly! As Firestore limits the use of only 10 where and a maximum of 1 whereIn per query, I don't know what the best approach is as I have no experience with NoSQL. If I make a query with the limit of possible filters and then apply the other filters manually on the client side, I fear that it will increase the cost with too much data transfer. On the other hand, if I apply a limit to this query before applying the manual filters, I can reduce the sampling too much to the point of not being able to combine the other filters manually. Got it? @AlexMamo

Yes, that's a trade between those approaches. So you have to choose which one is best for you.

So it is simply impossible to do a query with multiple filters in NoSQL? Can you see any solution to this problem using NoSQL? @AlexMamo

It is not possible to filter using multiple whereIn function calls, otherwise it is possible. For more alternative solutions I recommend you see, query Firestore multiple whereIn.
